# How to reuse getter/setter patterns in Typescript

Tags: typescript, decorator

I have a class that has several properties with the same pattern in getters/setters. I'd like to not duplicate the boilerplate, but I'm not sure how.

Is there a way to use decorators or some other language feature to accomplish this in the example class below?

```
export class Reaction {

  // These two properties have the same getter/setter pattern

  private _reactant1: State = null;
  get reactant1(): State {
    return this._reactant1;
  }
  set reactant1(newState: State) {
    if (this._reactant1) {
      this.deregister(this._reactant1);
    }

    this._reactant1 = newState;
    if (this._reactant1) {
      this.register(newState);
    }
  }

  private _reactant2: State = null;
  get reactant2(): State {
    return this._reactant2;
  }
  set reactant2(newState: State) {
    if (this._reactant2) {
      this.deregister(this._reactant2);
    }

    this._reactant2 = newState;
    if (this._reactant2) {
      this.register(newState);
    }
  }

  constructor(reactant1?: State,
              reactant2?: State) {

    if (reactant1) {
      this.reactant1 = reactant1;
    }
    if (reactant2) {
      this.reactant2 = reactant2;
    }
  }

  register(state: State) {
    if (state) {
      console.log('do a thing')
    }
  }

  deregister(state: State) {
    if (state) {
                console.log('do a thing')

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Is that something that happens a lot in your code? Because, while it is possible, it probably won't be that pretty.

Comment: This particular getter/setter combo is needed 6 times for this class. It happens a few other places in the code I'm working on now.